# Remove ID from all groups if ID meets a condition in at least one group in R

Tags: r, subset

I have SNP (allele) (column V1) frequencies (column V8) for different populations (column V9). Each SNP has an ID (specified in column V1). I want to remove the IDs whose value in V8 (allele frequency) is 0 or 1 in at least one group (dataframe is grouped by V9). Specifically, I want to remove the ID from the dataframe (all the groups), not only from the group where the condition is met.

```
  V1       V8            V9
1: rs10002235 0.324468     CARIBBEAN
2: rs10002235 0.176471     ADYGEI
3: rs10002235 0.305402     EUR
4: rs10002235 0.240384     AFR
5: rs10002235 0.495604     AMISH
6: rs10002235 0.096153     LATINO
1: rs33333235 0.5          CARIBBEAN
2: rs33333235 0.4          ADYGEI
3: rs33333235 0.3          EUR
4: rs33333235 0.001        AFR
5: rs33333235 0.4          AMISH
6: rs33333235 0.09         LATINO
```

If rs10002235 frequency (V8) was  <0.01 or >0.99 in any (at least one) of the groups specified in V9, it should be dropped from the dataframe.

Output would be like so:

```
   V1       V8            V9
    1: rs10002235 0.324468     CARIBBEAN
    2: rs10002235 0.176471        ADYGEI
    3: rs10002235 0.305402           EUR
    4: rs10002235 0.240384           AFR
    5: rs10002235 0.495604         AMISH
    6: rs10002235 0.096153        LATINO
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the ID column in posted data? V1? Are there other groups beyond what you show *within* V9 column? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71277911/edit) post for fuller before data and desired result and an even earnest attempt at the solution.

Comment: Yes the ID is in col V1. There are other groups but it should not matter for the logic of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `group_by` `V1` instead of `V9`
- Within each group, check if there exists a `V8` value <0.01 or >0.99. If so, remove all rows in the group using `any`.
- `ungroup`

```
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~V1, ~V8, ~V9,
    "rs10002235", 0.324468,"CARIBBEAN",
    "rs10002235", 0.176471, "ADYGEI",
    "rs10002235", 0.305402, "EUR",
    "rs10002235", 0.240384, "AFR",
    "rs10002235", 0.495604, "AMISH",
    "rs10002235", 0.096153, "LATINO",
    "rs33333235", 0.5, "CARIBBEAN",
    "rs33333235", 0.4, "ADYGEI",
    "rs33333235", 0.3, "EUR",
    "rs33333235", 0.001, "AFR",
    "rs33333235", 0.4, "AMISH",
    "rs33333235", 0.09, "LATINO"
)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(V1) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!any(V8>0.99 | V8<.01)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is `data.table`, grouped `by` the 'V1', check if `any` of the values in vector (`c(0, 1)`) are `%in%` 'V8', negate (`!`), extract the row sequence (`.I`), extract (`$tmp`) and use that to subset the groups (assuming precision is taken care off)

```
library(data.table)
dt1[dt1[, .(tmp = .I[(!any(V8 > 0.99|V8 <= 0.01)) & 
    ! any(c(0, 1) %in% V8)]), by = V1]$tmp]
```

-output

```
        V1       V8        V9
       <char>    <num>    <char>
1: rs10002235 0.324468 CARIBBEAN
2: rs10002235 0.176471    ADYGEI
3: rs10002235 0.305402       EUR
4: rs10002235 0.240384       AFR
5: rs10002235 0.495604     AMISH
6: rs10002235 0.096153    LATINO
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("rs10002235", "rs10002235", "rs10002235", 
"rs10002235", "rs10002235", "rs10002235", "rs33333235", "rs33333235", 
"rs33333235", "rs33333235", "rs33333235", "rs33333235"), V8 = c(0.324468, 
0.176471, 0.305402, 0.240384, 0.495604, 0.096153, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 
0.001, 0.4, 0.09), V9 = c("CARIBBEAN", "ADYGEI", "EUR", "AFR", 
"AMISH", "LATINO", "CARIBBEAN", "ADYGEI", "EUR", "AFR", "AMISH", 
"LATINO")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: The object is grouped by V9 (populations), not V1.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work. I end up with only 1 group out of 95 after applying the filter.

Comment: I clarified the question. The ID is in column 1. There are 95 groups but I don't see how the number of groups could matter. The code should work for any N groups.

Comment: I updated the post with the expected output

Comment: It's either condition A or B. Two different versions

Comment: Sorry about that...I had forgotten to change the frequencies for the second ID. Post updated.

Comment: The expected is fine. It's original dataframe without the second ID.  rs33333235  is dropped because  V8 is <0.01 for AFR group.

Comment: @DavidePiffer now you can check the output.  It matches.  The confusion was regarding which one was the grouping column

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave` to calculate groupwise max of condition. Then filter on this calculation.

```r
cond <- ave(
     as.integer(dt$V8 < 0.01 | dt$V8 > 0.99),
     dt$V1, 
     FUN = max
)

dt[cond == 1]
```